# recovering FTP password

Tags: ftp

The password for the ftp server is displaying as incorrect. It seems like someone has changed it. Is there any way of finding out what the password is?

Comment: Voted to move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way. If it's possible to get the password out without knowing it the password system would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to contact the host of the FTP server and request that they reset the password for you. They will then issue you a replacement password.

If it still does not work, you'll need to go through their support channels to troubleshoot the problem.